# get cart amount from external script

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, magento2.1.5, external

I want display the amount of items in the cart outside of magento.
Thus I created this script inside a scripts folder in the magento directory:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Set the state (not sure if this is neccessary)
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Getting the object managers dependencies 
$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$helper = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');

echo json_encode(['items' => $helper->getItemsQty()]);
```

But for an unknown reason this suddenly just returns zero. I did not update the version so I think it might be some setting maybe?

How do I get the amount of items in the cart outside of magento?

PS: I know there are several answers already but I tried them all and they did not work either for different reasons like errors or so.

**update:**

This seems to be some sort of Magento problem. After a night I called the page again and there is this strange behavior:

- the cart amount on the magento page still shows a number and the popover shows my items although I did not setup persistent cart but I set the session time to a high value
- if I go to the cart it is empty
- the script still shows zero

Now if I clear my browser data and call magento and the script again both display zero (as there is nothing in the cart for real). If I then add items to the cart both display the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Who is requesting this script url?

If its not the customer (who has items in his/her cart), the bootstrap may be creating a new customer/visitor session, thus having an empty cart.

If you are the owner running this script, you must load the cart/quote by its id from the quote repository, before retrieving the cart contents.

On the other hand, if the customer him/herself is calling this script, make sure the script is sharing the same php session to identify the customer and  retrieve his/her cart contents.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the customer is calling the script him/herself. but I found that it seems to be an magento problem. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the actual problem.
But the problem is related to my local dev-environment with vagrant.
After uploading it to my server I can't reproduce the error anymore.